# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 : Create custom annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to create a few custom annotations for an Entity class, i've come across [this article on Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/common/2.0/docs/reference/annotations/en) however i'm unsure as to how to integrate this into my Symfony bundle, can anybody shed some light on this?

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @myCustomVar(remember="true")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Thanks

Comment: Underlying question : are you supposed to integrate this in a bundle or are there pieces of code that you can put elsewhere? If you look at [the README of the doctrine extensions bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst), you'll see that this bundle is dependant on a library that will go inside lib/vendor, and that is not a bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspire you to the doctrine extension:

- The [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) library contains some annotation classes. But as this annotations does not mean anything for the Doctrine core, it's also this extension that is responsible of interpreting them. To do that, it uses some listeners that must be registered into the Doctrine's event dispatcher.
- In Symfony you can declare services with the `doctrine.event_listener` (or `doctrine.event_subscriber` for event subscribers) so the Doctrine bundle will find them and register them for you. The [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git) primarily aims to automate this part of event listeners registration.

Anyway, when you think about extending Doctrine, as it can be used without Symfony, prefer to divide your work in two parts: one is the doctrine extension, the other is the glue between this extension and Symfony and is called bundle.